# How to useState hook in expanded table in antd and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd editable table, the child column is expandable from the parent column. I want to be able to edit each row inline. So I have to capture the key of the row to be edited.

This works well for the parent table, but when I try to expand the table to display the children, i get the error
[image: error image]

I think It is because of the `useState` in the second function/component. cos when I comment it out, the error goes away. But Now, I am stuck on how to store state.

How can tell me how to implement this?

How come it works very well in the first one, but not the second one since both are identical?

This is my first function which generated the parent Table Columns

```
export const generateParentColumns = (dataSource: Record[]) => {
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const columns = [
    {
      key: "name",
      title: "Widget Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "30%",
    },
    {
      key: "displayTemplate",
      title: "Display Template",
      dataIndex: "displayTemplate",
      width: "30%",
    },
  
    ...
  ];


  return columns.map(col => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }
    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record: Record) => ({
        record,
        inputType: col.dataIndex === "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record, editingKey)
      })
    };
  });
};
```

The second one is almost identcial, with column differences

```
export const generateChildColumns = (
  dataSource: RECORD[]
  ) => {
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const save = (form: any, key: number) => {
    form.validateFields((error: any, row: any) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      console.log("Key =>", key);
    });
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      key: "type",
      title: "Type",
      dataIndex: "type",
      width: "20%",
    },
    ...
  ];

)
```

They are both in the same file. Although I have seperated it and still get the same error.

Child Table generator is

```
const handleExpandedRowRender = (record: Record) => {
    return (
      <Box>
        <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
          <Table
            dataSource={dataSource}
            columns={generateChildColumns(dataSource)}
          />
        </EditableContext.Provider>
      </Box>
    );
  };
```

Parent table generator is

```
 <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
      <Table
        dataSource={dataSource}
        loading={areWidgetsLoading}
        columns={generateParentColumns(dataSource)}
        onExpand={handleRowExpand}
        expandedRowRender={handleExpandedRowRender}
        expandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
      />
    </EditableContext.Provider>
```